# Saving odometry data:Conversion into "txt" / "CSV"

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to get the raw odometry data from the Rviz. Consider the following example i have implemented from one of the ROS Books in which the bot is supposed to move from one position to another and then come back to the starting point.

[image: image description]

As shown in the output, the arrows represents the odom data. I want to view this odom data in a file including the complete raw data of odom in text form of the whole process. I want to view the data the Rviz is planning at each instant of time. Is it feasible with ROS??
I tried the rosbag concept, but playing the generated bag file is not giving me the desired output.

Using ( http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/... , I tried the "rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic > data.txt" but I am getting a blank txt file " and i am not able to observe any output with the command "rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic.

On using the "rqt" command to check the data of the bag file, then i got the following output.
[image: image description]
This means that the bag file has the data, but then why am i getting a blank ".txt" file?? Also, how to understand the data the "rqt" is showing??
Also, why am i not able to get "csv" file?
Note: (Update from the suggested given answer) Using "rostopic echo /odom" is giving an appropriate change of odom values. But i want a user understandable set of odom values.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256776/saving-odometry-data:conversion-into-%22txt%22-/-%22csv%22/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is

```
rostopic echo /robot/odom
```

What you are looking For? Note that you May Change the topic name... Andere you can also Forward the output to a Text File using  > operator..

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-12**:
My requirement is similar to this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/?sort=votes&page=1#sort-top).
I also need to have info of each step taken by the bot during a simulation, the data processed by the odom in backhand and the laser data.

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-12**:
With this , i will then try to retrieve the data of arduino connected ROS and will get the raw data ROS is processing from the ultrasonic sensor. Somewhat similar to what i have asked in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/256554/ros-general-query-dealing-with-codes/).

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-12**:
Using (http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/?sort=votes&page=1#sort-top)command, I tried the "rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic > data.txt" but I am getting a blank txt file " and i am not able to observe any output with the command "rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2017-03-12**:
Did you Check your BAG contains the topic, rosbag info "File Name"?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2017-03-12**:
Also you can imspect the bag using rqt_bag

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-12**:
@Wolf, the question has been edited as per your suggested alternatives.
Regards

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2017-03-12**:
I think you can also right click or something to inspect the current message values of each topic in rqt

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-03-12**:
Yes sir. I saw the http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_bagand found how we can vary the view. I am now wondering how to save the data in a tabular or excel form ,ie: CSV / Txt format. Don't know why the CSV conversion command is not giving a result and why the txt file showing an empty file. any suggestions?